# Nightly build for android project using gradle

Tags: android, linux, git, gradle, nightly-build

I have an android project which I'm developing in windows environment.
Also a remote git repository exist which I push my project to it daily.
My requirement is to have a mechanism to automate daily(or nightly) builds.
I know that I can build my project in command line by aid of "gardlew.bat". This wrapper is special to my environment (windows) and I need to build the project on remote git repository which is on a linux machine.
How can i build my project on a linux machine using command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of your project's root files, you can find "gradlew.bat" that is meant to run on windows machines, and a "**gradlew**" file that is meant to run on a unix based system.

To build from unix command line, clone your entire project into the linux based machine and run the following command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

You need to make sure that your environment is set up correctly (JDK is installed and JAVA_HOME is configured correctly).

For detailed explanation, please refer to the [Android Studio developers site](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks.. It seems to be my solution. I'll test it and acknowledge you.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `Jenkins` and configure a job for building (and testing, if you have some tests) your application. Configure this job to run periodically (via embedded `cron`).

Jenkins can

- clone source code from the repo
- run `gradle` with the task(s) specified
- save *.apk (save `artifacts` in Jenkins terminology)
- run tests
- and many other useful things you may be interested in

Consult https://jenkins.io/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I know Jenkins but I want to use gradle and a scheduled script for nightly builds.

Comment: use `cron(1)` in this simple case.