# How to do a nightly build using Gradle?

Tags: android, linux, git, gradle, nightly-build

I can build my android project in command line with ./gradlew assembleDebug but how do I automate this so Gradle builds itself once every day? Is there any way to do this without downloading something additional like Jenkins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nightly build for android project using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847688/nightly-build-for-android-project-using-gradle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use crontab to automate without downloading any package type `crontab -e`

```
*     *     *     *     *  Command to be executed
```

1. Min (0 - 59)
2. Hour (0 - 23)
3. Day of month (1 - 31)
4. Month (1 - 12)
5. Day of week (0-7)

lets say if you want to automate everyday around 22:00

```
0 21 * * * ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux and can do it from the command line, you should look into [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). That's built into every Linux install I've ever seen.